# Learning React and using componentDidMount causes an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

Can anyone see why the following componentDidMount method causes an error please?  If the componentDidMount method is removed the map loads without error.

The error message is shown below.  When looking at the code in the browser (chrome tools) the 'this' is not set and hence causes an error.

**Offending method**

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      this.setState({
        location: {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        }
    });
  }
```

**Error message**

```
Line 35:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
```

**Complete code**

```
import React from 'react'
import L from 'leaflet'
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/maps-icon-12.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});

class MyMap extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      location: {
        lat: 10.7268906,
        lng: -30.3580425,
      },
      zoom: 13
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      this.setState({
        location: {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
       }
    });
  }

  render () {
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
    return (
        <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
        url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
          <Marker position={position} icon={myIcon}>
            <Popup>
              <span>Booyaa</span>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      )
  }
}

export default MyMap;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no closing `})` for `setState`.

The problem with `this` is that callback function has different context, while it's expected that lexical `this` should be used with arrow function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.setState({
        location: {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's got it.  I could see it was a context problem but why is the arrow function making it work?

Comment: That's what it's for. It cannot have its own `this` and allows to reach `this` from parent scope. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions